# Failed to run string.format + problem with exit button

Tags: java

I'm working on my first project. As I tried to go to a new line in the `string.format` it failed somehow (Either won't print at all or printing in same line).

Here is the code :

```
    String reciept = String.format("Recipt number #16424 +"  + "%n" + "Beef Burgers :" + ab1 +"%n" + "Cheese Burgers :" + ab2 + "%n" +   "Fish and Chips :" + ab3 + "%n"  + "French Fries :" + ab5 + "%n" +  "Steak :" + ab4 + "%n"  + "Sprite Drinks : " + ab + "%n" +  "Soda Drinks : " + ab8 + "%n" + "Fuzetea Drinks : " + ab7 + "%n" + "Coke Drinks :" + ab6 + "%n" , ab,ab1,ab2,ab3,ab4,ab5,ab6,ab7,ab8);
            recieptText.setText(reciept);
```

And 1 more question. I'm trying to create the `JButton` exit. I've tried to open a message that says if I'm sure exiting then quits but I failed so I tried the reg one if he presses exit it will exit and I failed as well.

```
JButton btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
btnExit.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 19));
btnExit.setBounds(766, 484, 127, 39);
if (btnExit.isSelected()==true) {
    System.exit(0);
}
frame.getContentPane().add(btnExit);
```

Comment: You should start learning java in a good website like tutorialspoint.

Comment: Hmm i try my best with videos in youtube , i like more doing than reading ,Anyways you know the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snow, you are at the beginning of a long but yet fun and fruitful journey. Good luck!
For your first question there are many right answers at different levels of perfection in terms of Object Oriented Design principles. I need to recommend you to read about Java coding standards, Inversion Of Control, Unit Testing as early as possible. I will just mention about encapsulation and recommend you the following solution.

I would first create two classes Receipt and ReceiptItem (Could create Product, ProductPrice, etc depending on the scope of the project) assuming that it is not only a single receipt you are trying to print (and probably for storing receipts for later inspection you will also need a persistence layer this is another field to explore for you), but you will handle many receipts with even more receipt detail lines. Then I would create instances of these 2 classes and invoke the method toFormattedString of Receipt class before sending it to the text display/print device.

```
public class ReceiptItem {
    private static final int TITLE_WIDTH = 30;
    private static final String DETAIL_FORMAT="%-" + TITLE_WIDTH + "s : %6s%n";

    private String title;
    private BigDecimal totalPrice;

    public ReceiptItem(String title, BigDecimal totalPrice) {
        setTitle(title);
        setTotalPrice(totalPrice);
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public BigDecimal getTotalPrice() {
        return totalPrice;
    }

    public void setTotalPrice(BigDecimal totalPrice) {
        this.totalPrice = totalPrice;
    }

    public String toFormattedString() {
        return String.format(DETAIL_FORMAT, getTitle(),
                getTotalPrice().toPlainString());
    }
}


public class Receipt {
    private static final String RECEIPT_HEADER_FORMAT = "Receipt number #%s%n";
    private static int LAST_RECEIPT_NUMBER = 0;
    private int receiptNumber;
    private List<ReceiptItem> items= new ArrayList<>();

    public Receipt() {
        super();
        setReceiptNumber(++LAST_RECEIPT_NUMBER);
    }

    public Receipt(int receiptNumber) {
        this();
        setReceiptNumber(LAST_RECEIPT_NUMBER=receiptNumber);
    }

    public void addItem(ReceiptItem item) {
        items.add(item);
    }

    public int getReceiptNumber() {
        return receiptNumber;
    }
    public void setReceiptNumber(int receiptNumber) {
        this.receiptNumber = receiptNumber;
    }
    public List<ReceiptItem> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
    public void setItems(List<ReceiptItem> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
    public String toFormattedString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(String.format(RECEIPT_HEADER_FORMAT, getReceiptNumber()));
        for (ReceiptItem item:getItems()) {
            builder.append(item.toFormattedString());
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}


Receipt receipt = new Receipt();
receipt.addItem(new ReceiptItem("Beef Burgers", new BigDecimal("5.00")));
receipt.addItem(new ReceiptItem("Cheese Burgers", new BigDecimal("5.00")));
receipt.addItem(new ReceiptItem("Fish and Chips", new BigDecimal("6.00")));
receipt.addItem(new ReceiptItem("French Fries", new BigDecimal("4.00")));
receipt.addItem(new ReceiptItem("Steak", new BigDecimal("10.00")));
receipt.addItem(new ReceiptItem("Sprite Drinks", new BigDecimal("1.00")));
receipt.addItem(new ReceiptItem("Soda Drinks", new BigDecimal("0.40")));
receipt.addItem(new ReceiptItem("Fuzetea Drinks", new BigDecimal("0.70")));
recieptText.setText(reciept.toFormattedString());
```

My answwer to your second question:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
//... Your code here
JButton btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
btnExit.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 19));
btnExit.setBounds(766, 484, 127, 39);
if (btnExit.isSelected()==true) {
    System.exit(0);
}

btnExit.addActionListener((e)-> {
    int confirm = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
            "Are You Sure to Close this Application?",
            "Exit Confirmation", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);
    if (confirm == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
});

frame.getContentPane().add(btnExit);
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        int confirm = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
                "Are You Sure to Close this Application?",
                "Exit Confirmation", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);
        if (confirm == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
});
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.pack();
```